# Corrupted .xlsx file from Flask web app and ajax POST request

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I have a Flask web app with a URL route that receives a post request with some json, parses it to an .xlsx file, then returns the file with `send_file()`.

Server side, I can see that the .xlsx file that is generated is correct but, once downloaded on the client side, the file is corrupted and can't be opened and is much larger than expected (201KB vs. 112KB).

I suspect it's some sort of encoding issue, but I've tried a whole bunch of stuff and can't make any headway. Can anyone help, please?

Flask route:

```
@app.route('/request/export_XLSX',methods=['POST'])
def request_export_XLSX():
        json_model = json_util.loads(request.data.decode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        xlsx_model = detox.xlsxFromJSONModel(json_model)  # Returns file path
        result = send_file(xlsx_model, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename=json_model['id']+'.xlsx', mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
        return result
```

JavaScript:

```
var exportModelExcel = function(){
        var model = detox.fba.model
        d3.selectAll('*').style("cursor","wait")
        var modelJson = JSON.stringify(model)
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/request/export_XLSX",
                data: modelJson,
                success: function(d){
                        d3.selectAll('*').style("cursor","")
                        var blob = new Blob([d], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'})
                        var link=document.createElement("a");
                        link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        link.download=model.id+".xlsx";
                        link.click();
                },
error: function(jqxhr,textStatus,errorThrown){
                        console.log("Error: " ,textStatus,errorThrown)
                        d3.selectAll('*').style("cursor","")
                        alert("There was an error exporting the model")
                },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                responseType: 'blob',
                processData: false,
        });
}
```

Here's a link where you can see the good and bad .xlsx files: https://gofile.io/d/xywI1D

Comment: I doubt it's an encoding issue on the Flask side, since it would be a binary. I'm wondering what happens if you just send the browser to the file URL instead of using your client-side trick to download the file. Does it look any different then?

Comment: Also for security reasons, I didn't open your files (I'm sure you understand), but I did try inspecting the files with the Unix file command. It reports the _bad file as a Zip archive data, while the good file is reported as a Microsoft Excel file. That might shed some light into it, but I'm not sure what?

Comment: In the bad file, every non-ascii byte has been replaced with EFBFBD, the unicode replacement character. Xlsx files are zipped xml, and enough of the zip header survives to fool `file` - but it can't tell it is xlsx without looking at the contents.

Comment: Try adding the header Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 to your request, as is suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318314/linux-to-windows-bad-encoding-response

Answer (score 3):

Well, I ended up ripping out the ajax and using an `XMLHTTPRequest` instead.

It works nicely and results in an uncorrupted .xlsx file.

```
var exportModelExcel = function(){
        var model = detox.fba.model;
        var modelJson = JSON.stringify(model);
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(xhttp.response);
                        var a = document.createElement("a");
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.style = "display: none";
                        a.href = downloadUrl;
                        a.download = model.id+".xlsx";
                        a.click();
                }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "/request/export_XLSX", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhttp.responseType = "blob";
        xhttp.send(modelJson);
}
```